# How do I change characters in The Ruins of Sarudnahk?

Tags: evoland

Shortly after reaching The Ruins of Sarudnahk, you encounter a Diablo-esque dungeon that unlocks the option to play as either the protagonist Clink or the mage Kaeris. (Previously she was relegated to a secondary party member)

I initially selected Kaeris with the intention of swapping back later, but I couldn’t find an option to swap characters afterwards.

How do I change characters after reaching The Ruins of Sarudnahk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no option to change characters dynamically, as stated on [Gamefaqs forums](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/705797-evoland/66025902):

> I'm pretty sure there's no way to change again.

and [Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/233470/discussions/0/864977025898690016/):

> I don't think you can change it once you have chosen.
>
> [...]
>
> Yeah, I just restarted the game.

However, [Steam user Link2434](https://steamcommunity.com/app/233470/discussions/0/864972399678918707/) said:

> If you chose Kaeris, don't worry; you'll later be able to come back as
> Clink

So surely no option to change directly, but "maybe" another chance later in the game.